# How should I add records to contentPart?

Tags: orchardcms

Lets say I have a model like this one:

```
public class LicenceProductRecord : ContentPartRecord 
{
    public LicenceProductRecord() 
    {
        Details = new List<LicenceProductDetailRecord>();
    }
    public virtual string Sku { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<LicenceProductDetailRecord> Details { get; set; }
}

public class LicenceProductDetailRecord 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    //fk on licenceProductRecord...
    public virtual int LicenceProductRecord_Id { get; set; } 
    //id from external source
    public virtual string LicenceId { get; set; }
    //options
    public virtual string Features { get; set; }
}

public class LicenceProductPart : ContentPart<LicenceProductRecord>
{
    [Required]
    public string Sku
    {
        get { return Record.Sku; }
        set { Record.Sku = value; }
    }

    public IList<LicenceProductDetailRecord> Products 
    {
        get { return Record.Details;  }
        set { Record.Details = value; }
    }
}
```

Handler and drivers for LicenceProductPart are "standard" per ContentPart.
I then added a LicenceProductController to manage adding/removing of Details of a LicenceProductPart.
How do I add(or remove) a LicenceProductDetailRecord from this controller? I did something like this but it does not commit to the db:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNewProduct(string licProdId, int licPartId)
    {
        var part = _services.ContentManager.GetLatest<LicenceProductPart>(licPartId);
        var pInfo = _catalogProvider.GetProductInfo(licProdId);//this is info from external catalog

        var newProdDetailRec = new LicenceProductDetailRecord();
        newProdDetailRec.LicenceProductRecord_Id = part.Id;
        newProdDetailRec.ProductId = pInfo.Id;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in pInfo.Features)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1};",item.FeatureId,item.FeatureValue);
        }
        newProdDetailRec.Features = sb.ToString();

        //_productDetailRepository.Create(newProdDetailRec);
        //_productDetailRepository.Flush();

        part.Products.Add(newProdDetailRec);
        _services.ContentManager.Publish(part.ContentItem);

        var shape = _services.New.EditorTemplate(
                TemplateName: "Parts/LicenceProduct",
                Model: LicenceProductViewModel.Map( part, _catalogProvider));
        return new ShapeResult(this, shape);
    }
```

How should I work with members(IList) of ContentPart like one in this model?

Comment: Hm, it works now, after I have done Orchard setup again. I've seen a post about mappings.bin might have been cached or something like it. This code now actually does updates the db: uncomment the _productDetailRepository.Create and comment the prt.Products.Add and _services.ContentManager.Publish. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to make a contentPart for LicenceProductDetailRecord and include that inside the LicenceProductPart as a list. That would create a detailed record for each part you have in the list. On the parts not committing to the database, I use the following method for my items.

1. I create a content item that contains the part (in line or
   in the migration) say call it productItem.
2. I use orchard content manager to create the item and the
       parts it contains 
       orchardServices.ContentManager.Create(productItem,
       VersionOptions.Published);
3. use the part I am interested in like this 
   var productPart = productItem.As();

when you change values in productPart they will persist tot he database.

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: That would be one way but I don't want LicenceProductDetail to be a content part. Thanks for the effort.